# What is the TensorFlow checkpoint meta file?

Tags: tensorflow

When saving a checkpoint, TensorFlow often saves a meta file: `my_model.ckpt.meta`. What is in that file, can we still restore a model even if we delete it and what kind of info did we lose if we restore a model without the meta file?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This file contains a serialized [`MetaGraphDef` protocol buffer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.proto). The `MetaGraphDef` is designed as a serialization format that includes all of the information required to restore a training or inference process (including the [`GraphDef`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.proto) that describes the dataflow, and additional annotations that describe the variables, input pipelines, and other relevant information). For example, the `MetaGraphDef` is used by [TensorFlow Serving](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic.html) to start an inference service based on your trained model. We are investigating other tools that could use the `MetaGraphDef` for training.

Assuming that you still have the Python code for your model, you do not need the `MetaGraphDef` to restore the model, because you can reconstruct all of the information in the `MetaGraphDef` by re-executing the Python code that builds the model. To restore from a checkpoint, you only need the checkpoint files that contain the trained weights, which are written periodically to the same directory.

Comment: Is there a way to load these with the C++ api? I'm running into trouble executing graphs in C++ because the variables are not initialized with regular GraphDef protos.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and it helps a lot.

Comment: Hi @mrry, when I save multiple checkpoints with global steps, it results in multiple ```name-step.cpkt``` and ```name-step.cpkt.meta```, but there's only 1 ```checkpoint``` file. What is this ```checkpoint``` file and why aren't there as many of this file as ```name-step.cpkt``` please?

Comment: The `"checkpoint"` file contains a serialized `CheckpointState` protocol buffer, which contains pointers to the most recent checkpoints of the model. It is rewritten each time a checkpoint is saved, to give a single location where information about the up-to-date checkpoints is stored.

Comment: I do not see .ckpt file but I see .ckpt-n-meta and .ckpt-n-.data-0000 of 0001 and .ckpt-n-index files (where n is number of iteration). What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @Chandra: The checkpoint format was changed in TensorFlow 0.12. Checkpoints now contain multiple files. If you want to use the old (less efficient) format, you can create your saver as `tf.train.Saver(..., write_veresion=tf.train.SaverDef.V1)`.

Comment: @mrry: How can we load the graph and the Variables from these 3 files in C++? The label_image example loads the model using a single .bp file.