# model saver meta file is huge, can I configure tensorflow to not write it?

Tags: tensorflow

I am doing transfer learning in tensorflow with [vgg16](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~frossard/post/vgg16/). I am only training one small layer on top of the 500MB of weights that I got from the numpy npz file on that website. When I save my model, I am specifying just the weights I am training, so the model file is small - however the meta file is 500MB. From reading [stackoverflow: what-is-the-tensorflow-checkpoint-meta-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195454/what-is-the-tensorflow-checkpoint-meta-file) it sounds safe to remove the meta files, but can I configure tensorflow to not write them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the `tf.train.Saver.save` with the optional `write_meta_graph=False` param.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver