# What do the .index and .data-00000-of-00001 files produced after saving in TensorFlow represent?

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf

# construct graph
v1 = tf.Variable([0], name='v1')
v2 = tf.Variable([0], name='v2')

# run graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  saver.save(sess, 'ckp')
```

What is the relationship between the index file and the data file?

```
.
├── checkpoint
├── ckp.data-00000-of-00001
├── ckp.index
├── ckp.meta
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be found from the [comments in TF source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/util/tensor_bundle/tensor_bundle.h#L30).

> The ".index" file is a string-string immutable table
>   (tensorflow::table::Table).  Each key is a name of a tensor and its
>   value is a serialized BundleEntryProto.  Each BundleEntryProto
>   describes the metadata of a tensor: which of the "data" files contains
>   the content of a tensor, the offset into that file, checksum, some
>   auxiliary data, etc.

Answer (score 6):

This question is similar to [TensorFlow, why there are 3 files after saving the model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265035/tensorflow-why-there-are-3-files-after-saving-the-model), but that does not discuss in detail what are `.index` and `.data-00000-of-00001` files.

Similarly, [What is the TensorFlow checkpoint meta file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195454/what-is-the-tensorflow-checkpoint-meta-file) answers what does `.meta` file do.

`.index` stores the list of variable names and shapes saved. Hence, it is usually much smaller in size. `.data-00000-of-00001` stores the actual values of all the variables saved. Hence, it is usually much larger in size.

We can test it out with the code below. But before this, run the MNIST example in `tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py` to generate the log files.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.training import checkpoint_utils as cp

print cp.list_variables('/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/logs/fully_connected_feed/model.ckpt-1999')
print cp.load_variable('/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/logs/fully_connected_feed/model.ckpt-1999', 'hidden1/biases')
```

`cp.list_variables` then prints out the following:

```
[('global_step', []), ('hidden1/biases', [128]), ('hidden1/weights', [784, 128]), ('hidden2/biases', [32]), ('hidden2/weights', [128, 32]), ('softmax_linear/biases', [10]), ('softmax_linear/weights', [32, 10])]
```

`cp.load_variable` then prints out the entire vector of floating point values:

```
[  1.49112539e-02   2.43028291e-02   1.82662811e-02   2.32475083e-02
  -7.84891471e-03   1.87947564e-02  -6.21244172e-03   9.12105478e-03
  -1.70869497e-03   2.94519793e-02   6.23045377e-02   1.99174266e-02
   ...
   1.13238255e-02  -1.11185517e-02   2.25203596e-02  -4.95722517e-04
   1.22644939e-02   9.39049758e-03   3.05090044e-02   1.62753556e-02
   2.32785419e-02   3.78636681e-02   2.61069946e-02   2.02859659e-02]
```

`cp.list_variables` can run with only `.index` present, but `cp.load_variable` requires both `.index` and `.data-00000-of-00001` to run.

Comment: Cloud you clarify what does that numbers mean `00000` and `00001` in `variables.data-?????-of-?????` file?