# loading gpt2 simple checkpoint getting OpError: /content/model.data-00000-of-00001; No such file or directory

Tags: huggingface-transformers, gpt-2

I'm trying to use the checkpoint from a finetuned gpt-2-simple to use in my modified version of this gpt2 output detector https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11OZknA7er__NgH-Yje7__LY5v-huYE0P?usp=share_link

My saved checkpoint has the following files:
encoder.json,
hparams.json,
model-1000.data-00000-of-00001,
model-1000.index,
model-1000.meta,
vocab.bpe

I'm trying to load this to export it to onnx and then to use the detector.

I have tried:

```
config = transformers.GPT2Config.from_pretrained('/content/hparams.json')
tokenizer = transformers.GPT2Tokenizer("/content/encoder.json", "/content/vocab.bpe")
model = transformers.GPT2Model.from_pretrained('/content/model.index',from_tf=True,config=config)
```

But I get error: `OpError: /content/model.data-00000-of-00001; No such file or directory`

In the original collab they load the checkpoint directly from gpt2 so I can't use the same process.

I understand it's complaining it doesn't have the model-1000.data-00000-of-00001 file. What I don't understand and haven't been able to find is how to load it into this model.

I have seen these two StackOverflow answers that explain what the files are but not how to load a checkpoint into a model.

[What do the .index and .data-00000-of-00001 files produced after saving in TensorFlow represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023500/what-do-the-index-and-data-00000-of-00001-files-produced-after-saving-in-tenso)
[TensorFlow, why there are 3 files after saving the model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265035/tensorflow-why-there-are-3-files-after-saving-the-model)

Where is the.data-00000-of-00001 file supposed to be loaded and how? Is this possible?